# Processing HAML from database in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Wondering if it's possible to process HAML from database entries. My model currently processes HTML just fine, but I'd rather input HAML, and have the view process it into HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haml can be used programmatically: http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Engine.html

There isn't enough detail in your question for me to give a more specific answer.

Comment: For example, a table 'input' with a :text column 'text'.  I would save HAML formatted text to that field, then render it in a view with something like <%= input.text %> This renders plain-text, whereas if I save HTML, the HTML gets rendered correctly.  I will look into that link and see if I can figure out the correct syntax for such a situation, thanks.

Comment: = Haml::Engine.new(input.text).render(self) -- this works perfectly.  Any idea how to go about sanitizing that?

Comment: I'm not aware of sanitisers for Haml that you could apply before saving user input to the database. However, maybe you could sanitise the rendered HTML before returning it to the client?

Answer (score 8):

If your view is being replaced entirely by something coming from your model/database, you can use `render :inline` [to process it](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000464):

```
render :inline => @model.haml, :type => 'haml', :layout => true
```